# Cannot update database

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['password']))
    {
    // if the user has just tried to log in
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $db_conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'passwd', 'dbname');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Connection to database failed:'.mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
    }

    $query = 'select * from users '
           ."where userid like'$userid' "
           ." and password like sha1('$password')";

    $result = $db_conn->query($query);


    if ($result->num_rows >0 )
    {
     // if they are in the database register the user id
     $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $userid;    
    }
    $db_conn->close();
    }
    ?>
    <?

     $db_conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'passwd', 'dbname');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Connection to database failed:'.mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
    }


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty ($_POST['dob']) || empty ($_POST['contact'])|| empty          ($_POST['address'])|| empty ($_POST['email'])) {
    echo "All records to be filled in";
    exit;}
    }
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $userid = $_SESSION['valid_user'];
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET name=$name, dob=$dob, contact=$contact, address=$address, email=$email
    WHERE userid ='$userid'";
      $result = $db_conn->query($sql);
    if (!$result) 
        echo "Your query failed.";
    else
        echo "User Information Updated ";

?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=members.php" />
```

I got `your query failed` when I run it. Anyone have any clue why my database dont get updated?

I'm pretty sure my sql works. Is there any mistake in my coding?

Comment: Did you check the mysql error returned ?

Comment: Why aren't you using MySQLi prepared statements?

Comment: Try to echo your queries and copy/paste it in your db query tool, you will find what's wrong on your own ! And by the way, don't use like without a good reason, use = instead.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you seen what error the query returns?

Comment: `"UPDATE users SET name='$name', dob='$dob', contact='$contact', address='$address', email='$email' WHERE userid ='$userid'";` (possible target of sql injection)

Comment: Small note, but both including the credentials directly in your code and then pasting them into Stackoverflow are both pretty bad ideas.

Comment: I think there is a buggy field, look for some field definition missing the attribute name

Answer (score 2):

Your query is okay, except that you're not using prepared statements.

The issue lies in your variables. `echo` them and see what's in them.

Since we don't have access to your database it's hard for us to verify if something else might be wrong with your query. You could for example create an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Something else you should read up on: [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

[Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) look like this:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$city = "Amersfoort";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your `exist` statement is wrong..

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
 {
    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty ($_POST['dob']) || empty ($_POST['contact'])|| empty          ($_POST['address'])|| empty ($_POST['email'])) 
    {
        echo "All records to be filled in";
        **exit**;
    }
 }
```